# win32 Textbox and AnimateWindow

Tags: c, winapi, textbox, animatewindow

I'm making a native win32 application and use AnimateWindow to fadein the window. It all works well except the couple textboxes I have in my window are not drawn until I do an InvalidateRect call after the fadein. From the [MSDN doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632669%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) it says the WM_PRINTCLIENT message must be handled for custom controls to draw correctly, but that it isnt needed for common controls. Why do TEXT controls not work correctly? And how do I implement WM_PRINTCLIENT for my TEXT controls? Here's what I tried already with no success in my WndProc function:

```
...
case WM_PRINTCLIENT:
SendMessage(hTextCtl, WM_PRINT, wParam, PRF_OWNED);
break;
```

Comment: Which window procedure is that code snippet in? Do your "TEXT controls" use the `EDIT` window class?

Comment: This is in the WndProc function as I mentionned (I have only one), and yes hTextCtl is a handle to an EDIT control

Comment: Nevermind, solved the problem using WS_EX_LAYERED and SetLayeredWindowAttributes to set the transparency in case anyone has the same problem

Comment: Just note that `WS_EX_LAYERED` is only supported for child windows in Windows 8.1 and up.